# Firebase Crash report email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have implemented **Firebase** crash report basic setup for my project and it worked perfectly without any problem. Is it possible to get those error report on my **email**? I am unable to find email sending feature for non fatal or fatal error on crash report dashboard.

`FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Firebase non-fatal error on Android"));`

Comment: You can share via intent, to share same log

Comment: why intent in google analytics we are getting email directly without intent. So this is possible in Firebase.

Comment: I believe there's no way you can do so, using Firebase.

Comment: Good.. Can you please put that in Answer.

Comment: No.. Its not answer. Hence, I can't. Don't worry. I am not aggressive about points :)

Comment: Chintan is correct, currently the Firebase console is the only place where you can view the crash reports.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, you can get error reports on your email, in 5 simple steps:

1. Go to the [subscriptions tab on the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/subscriptions/overview).
2. Select your project
3. You'll see two options: one for new clusters and one for regressions.
4. When you click on one of those, you'll see an email checkbox. Check it and click on save.
5. Done, now you can get the reports on the email account that you used to sign up for Firebase.

Comment: It'd be useful to be able to specify the email address where you want to receive these alerts.

Comment: Hi, what if I want to send email notificaitons to other team members? I tried to add other users as viewers but they are receiving emails only if they have owner permissions

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/)
2. Click on bell icon at the top-right corner
3. Select your project from the dropdown list
4. Click on "Manage your alerts"

Select checkbox under email column to receive notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Click on this link and Select project from Feature Alert Section.
You will get settings for all features like Crashlytics, Crash Reporting,
Authentication, Hosting, Database etc.

https://console.firebase.google.com/subscriptions/overview