# send Firebase CrashReporting on my email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am connecting a Firebase Crash Reporting, but I can't set up sending messages to a my mail. I can configure sending reports in a Firebase console but messages are sending to emails of all people who are working with Firebase. How I can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504735/firebase-crash-report-email

Comment: Doug, I mean no Fairebase email) You answered in your youtube chanal. "Doug Stevenson:
You can only get email if you're added to the project via the project permissions (IAM)."  Thank, it's helps!