# Get notifications from crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I added crashlytics to my app. Now I can see error reports. They appear after 10-15 minutes. But I would like to receive notifications (by email?) about these errors. Is it possible?

Comment: You will be getting email about crashes on same mail id on which you have configured the project . You can also add other users i guess from console

Comment: do you mean my Google account email? Nothing comes in there. Do you know where to look for these settings?

Comment: I find solution here. This is actually done via the console https://stackoverflow.com/a/56851654/13434654